# Why don't my types works with my prisma schema? (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, express, serverless-framework, prisma

So I have a simple schema and it works but the moment I try to do anything with my defines types it doesn't work. Am I going about this correctly?

Here is my schema

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id         String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email      String     @unique
  given_name String
  last_name  String
  loginInfo  loginStats
  role       Role       @default(User)
  Articles   Article[]
}

model Article {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  title     String
  author    User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String?  @db.ObjectId
}

type loginStats {
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  lastLogin DateTime
}

enum Role {
  User
  Admin
}
```

Here is my test function to create a user.

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import cognitoUserPoolHelper from "../authLogin";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const test = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (!prisma) {
        console.log(req);
    }
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            email: "randoms@example.com",
            given_name: "Test",
            last_name: "Test",
            loginInfo: {
                set: {
                    createdAt: Date.now().toString(),
                    lastLogin: Date.now().toString(),
                },
            },
        },
    });
    console.log(user);

    res.json({
        msg: "Hello World",
    });
};
```

I am getting this error when I run it.

```
Unknown arg `set` in data.loginInfo.set for type loginStatsCreateInput. Did you mean `select`?
Argument lastLogin for data.loginInfo.lastLogin is missing.
```

I have generated my prisma schema so I can rule that out at least.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: It says you that it doesn't understand your `set` function call. Can you try removing it from where you provide `loginInfo` and just have it as nested object there. PS I have never used Prisma myself, so this could be just a brainfart :D

Comment: And also if you already have `createdAt DateTime @default(now())` in your loginStats schema you don't need to explicitly provide it's value when you create it

Comment: Removing it results in an error sadly. Need something in that slot from what I can tell.
Thanks. Ill change that over.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately get this same issue frequently when trying to create nested composite types. This error gets thrown whenever anything downstream is not correct, but isn't particularly helpful in identifying the problem. I would try setting the date method to a variable and injecting it in case it is an issue with Prisma manipulating the data in the Prisma client. It's infuriating the error message and the docs aren't very helpful in this case.

Comment: To follow up on this, for my similar error the problem ended up being a type error on one property and a misspelling on the other, but the error thrown was still "Unknown arg `set`." I'd still play with the date function first as that seems like the likely source of some funny business on the prisma side either not executing it or something